# toFixed equivalent that returns a type of number

Tags: javascript

I have a field that should return decimal numbers. I am formatting the user input, by adding 2 decimal places when onBlur action happens. This is the  field:

```
<NumericField
    name="workPercentage"
    validate={[required, maxValue100, hasValidDecimal]}
    normalizeOnBlur={value => (Number.isNaN(value) ? value : parseFloat(value).toFixed(2))}
/>
```

How can I get a number, instead of the string, where I would get the format that would add two decimal zeros to a number if a user would write a number with franction, like 75 for example. Since toFixed return string I can't use that because I need to return number to backend, and if I wrap the whole `parseFloat(value).toFixed(2))` with `Number` or another `parseFloat` it strips the zeros:

```
parseFloat(parseFloat(value).toFixed(2)))
```

How can I adjust this function to return formatted number.

Comment: You can't. A decimal number only has the number of decimals that are needed, but not more.

Comment: Real numbers don’t have trailing zeros after the decimal point.

Comment: The backend needs to normalise the number anyway, so why do you care?

Comment: I was just wondering if there is a possibility to convert it to type of number, but I guess it will have to be done in the backend.